# Center SubViews in ParentView in Objective-C

Tags: ios

I have the following code:

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
parentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

parentView.center = self.view.center;

parentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init];

subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

subView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);

subView.center = parentView.center;

[parentView addSubview:subView];

[self.view addSubview:parentView];
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

Why is the red view not centered in the green view since they have the same center?

Comment: Try to print the frame of both view and check. After setting center.

Comment: They share the same exact center. I printed the values and they are same.

Comment: That was your issue. Now you understand what is the problem. :)

Comment: @johndoe they share the same coordinates for their centre property. They do not, however, share the same coordinate space. 0, 0 for the green view is in the top left of the screen. 0, 0 for the red view is in the top left corner of the green view.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple `UIView` documentation states for the `center` property:

> The center is specified within the coordinate system of its superview and is measured in points. Setting this property changes the values of the frame properties accordingly.

That means the `parentView` center will be relative to its superview (the white background view by the looks of your screenshot).

To get the desired result you need to  do something like this:

```
subview.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(parentView.bounds),
                             CGRectGetMidY(parentView.bounds));
```

But you should really be using autolayout for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the green view to be the center of it's superview, but you are setting the red view to be in the center of it's superview's superview...

The way to fix that with the smallest amount of code change would be to change the red view's superview.

```
[self.view addSubview:parentView];
[self.view addSubview:subView];
```

EDIT:  To explain a little further what is going on.  Say when you set the center of your green view it gets set to (500,500).  That's inside it's superview, so it gets set to the middle of the screen.  Then you set your red view's center to the same value as the green view's center, (500,500).  But it's parent that it is relative to is the red view, so it gets placed (500,500) from the origin point of the green view.  It gets placed near the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: But in my case greenview, redview they share the same center as the root view which is self.view.

Comment: I think I understand. When the redView is added to the greenView then the redView will use the coordinates/frame/bounds provided by the greenView.

Comment: @johndoe Edited to explain a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

> You are Doing Like this

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
parentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

parentView.center = self.view.center;

parentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];


UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init];

subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

CGFloat SubviewX = (parentView.frame.size.width - 50)/2;
CGFloat SubviewY = (parentView.frame.size.height - 50)/2;

subView.frame = CGRectMake(SubviewX, SubviewY, 50, 50);


[parentView addSubview:subView];
[self.view addSubview:parentView];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to center a view, and maintain it that way even if the view changes its view frame is using constraints:

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
parentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// You might want to add constraints for the view's size
parentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

parentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

[self.view addSubview:parentView];

NSContraint *xContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:parentView
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:0.0];

[self.view addConstraint:xContraint];

NSContraint *yContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:parentView
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:0.0];

[self.view addConstraint:yContraint];

UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init];
subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// You might want to add constraints for the view's size
subView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);

subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[parentView addSubview:subView];

NSContraint *xSubContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:parentView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0];

[parentView addConstraint:xSubContraint];

NSContraint *ySubContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:parentView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0];

[parentView addConstraint:ySubContraint];
```

Comment: @marosoaie besides both view's frame sizes, why should this code have conflicts?